# react-router - Navigate to parent route from nested router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm playing around with `react-router`, and I have a problem when using nested routes.

Here is my parent router:

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/account" component={AccountDashboard} />
     </div>
 </Router>
```

Here is the router inside `AccountDashboard`:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/account/password-reset" component={ChangePassword} />
    <Route path="/account/sign-out" component={SignOut} />
</Router>
```

Once I navigate to either `/account/password-reset` or `/account/sign-out`, I can't seem to navigate back to the root of the parent router (to view the `HomePage` component). The child router is just returning null.

For example, I tried calling both `props.history.push('/')` and `props.history.reset('/')` within the `ChangePassword` component, but the child router returns null.

If I add a route for `'/'` in the AccountDashboard router, any component I provide will render just fine because the router in AccountDashboard matches it, but I want to redirect to `'/'` within the ChangePassword component and show the `HomePage` component via the parent router.

How do I navigate to a route on a parent router within a child/nested router?

### Edit: I just made a basic implementation from scratch, same problem:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Blue = withRouter(({ history }) => (
  <div style={{ border: "1px solid #222", width: "300px", padding: "4px", margin: "4px"}}>
    <h2>Blue Component</h2>
    <span
      style={{color: 'blue', textDecoration: 'underline'}}
      onClick={() => { history.replace('/') }}>
      Go back to Letters
    </span>
  </div>
));

const Green = withRouter(({ history }) => (
  <div style={{ border: "1px solid #222", width: "300px", padding: "4px", margin: "4px"}}>
    <h2>Green Component</h2>
    <span
      style={{color: 'blue', textDecoration: 'underline'}}
      onClick={() => { history.replace('/') }}>
      Go back to Letters
    </span>
  </div>
));

const Letters = () => (
  <div style={{ border: "1px solid #222", width: "300px", padding: "4px", margin: "4px"}}>
    <h2>Letters (Root) Component</h2>
  </div>
)
const Colors = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
    Child Router
    <br></br>
    [ <Link to="/colors/blue">Blue</Link> ]
    [ <Link to="/colors/green">Green</Link> ]
      <Route path="/colors/blue" exact component={Blue} />
      <Route path="/colors/green" component={Green} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
        Parent Router
        <br></br>
        [ <Link to="/">Letters</Link> ][ <Link to="/colors">Colors</Link> ]
          <Route path="/" exact component={Letters} />
          <Route path="/colors" component={Colors} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

With the above code, the app will load and display the `Letters` component. If you click on `Colors`, you'll be taken to the second router, where you can select 'Blue' or 'Green', which each have a link back to '/'. When you follow that link, the URL changes correctly to '/', but the original `Letters` component does not display.

Comment: Are you saying that when you press the back button from a Child component, it is not returning to the previous page? Or that a `<Link>` to "/" in the Child component is not working either?

Comment: Is there any reason for using two Routers in your app? You should only have one router at the top level. Does this sandbox do what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/8kwy5pkvm8 ?

Comment: You are completely right. I shouldn't have two routers. Once I removed the extra `Router` tags from around the other child routes, everything worked like a charm. If you could post that as an answer, I would be happy to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

@butchyyyy answered this for me in the comments but I'm answering in case someone else will find it.

**he said:** Is there any reason for using two Routers in your app? You should only have one router at the top level. Does this sandbox do what you want: codesandbox.io/s/8kwy5pkvm8

I have a main Navigation with a switch and one of the pages had a sub navigation.

What worked for me was to simply remove the second router component and use the parent path within child paths.

This is what the child component looks like:

```
const Apps = () => (
    <div className='main-container'>
    <SubNav items={subNavOptions} />
    <Route exact path='/apps' component={Applist} />
    <Route path='/apps/single-choice-lists' component={SingleChoiceLists} />
    <Route path='/apps/classification-sets' component={ClassificationSets} />
  </div>
)
```

Hope this helps someone else.